# Reconstruct pandas dataframe with users (rows) and items (column) so that each row is a user-item interaction

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with each row representing a user, and each column an item that they bought. The values in the cells are the number of times the item was purchased:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item A':[0,0,1], 'Item B':[1,1,2], 'Item C':[0,1,2]})
df

  | Item A | Item B | Item C
-----------------------------
0 |   0    |    1   |    0
1 |   0    |    1   |    1
2 |   1    |    2   |    2
```

I would like to reorganize this so I have a separate row for each user-item interaction. What I would like to get is this:

```
 User |   Item   |  Bought
----------------------------
  0   |  Item A  |    0
  0   |  Item B  |    1
  0   |  Item C  |    0
  1   |  Item A  |    0
  1   |  Item B  |    1
  1   |  Item C  |    1
  2   |  Item A  |    1
  2   |  Item B  |    2
  2   |  Item C  |    2
```

What would be the best way to do this? (Using melt doesn't give me exactly what I'm looking for here.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe, but first create *user* from index values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item A':[0,0,1], 'Item B':[1,1,2], 'Item C':[0,1,2]})
df['User'] = df.index

dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars='User', var_name='Item', value_name='Bought').\
        sort_values('User').reset_index(drop=True)

#    User    Item  Bought
# 0     0  Item A       0
# 1     0  Item B       1
# 2     0  Item C       0
# 3     1  Item A       0
# 4     1  Item B       1
# 5     1  Item C       1
# 6     2  Item A       1
# 7     2  Item B       2
# 8     2  Item C       2
```